# Deducting related educational trading expenses from LLC?

Tags: united-states, trading, small-business, eligible-expenses

From what I understand, you need to trade full-time in order to deduct educational related trading expenses such as magazines, courses, or newsletter subscriptions.  If I'm not a full-time trader but create an LLC that has its own bank account and trading account under the LLC, can the above type of educational expenses then be deducted?

Comment: A comment/observation. An LLC is a pass thru entity. I'm not aware of it providing changes to taxation as you're seeking. But someone more knowledgeable might have a better real answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single member llc is a tax nothing, a disregarded entity that does not affect tax filing unless you elect to pay entity/corporate tax.  It will not alter your status or increase your reach.

The rules to deduct expenses stem from [IRC §212](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/212) and Reg [§1.212-1](http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.212-1), and are partially explained in [Pub 550](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p550.pdf) and [Pub 535](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p535.pdf).  The llc will get these deductions if you check the box with [Form 8832](http://www.irs.gov/file_source/pub/irs-pdf/f8832.pdf), but it will then be paying corporate tax.  You may also hit certain tax rules for investment companies or [Personal Holding Companies](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/543).

Note that an LLC will not be taxed at a beneficial capital gains rate.

Comment: What do you mean by "beneficial capital gains rate"?

Comment: @NL7 - excellent. I have an LLC, and my purpose was to limit my personal liability as the acronym implies. Nice answer, keep them coming.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: As it seems I can't deduct educational related expenses, personal liability was the other deciding factor for putting together the LLC.  It's enough alone to form the LLC.

Comment: @4thSpace - Income is generally grouped into "ordinary income" and "capital gains."  For individuals in the US, the normal long-term [capital gains tax rate](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1#h) tops out at 20% (previously 15%).  There are multiple different CG rates, such as short-term, collectibles, QSBS, etc.  Corporate taxpayers still have capital gains, which track separately from their ordinary income, but they do not receive a preferential rate.  They pay the [corporate rate](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/11) on both OI and CG.

Comment: @4thSpace - I wouldn't say that investor education is necessarily not deductible.  You should dive into it and then consult a CPA or tax lawyer.  I saw some stuff suggesting that travel, publications, and maybe education could be investment expenses, but I did not look at the details.  There are probably Revenue Rulings or court cases on point.  IRC §212 is the relevant code section.